# How do I install curl with http2 support

Tags: 16.04, curl, https

It seems like curl packed with ubuntu 16.04 does not have http2 support. How do I enable http2 in curl

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As of now (Jan 2018). You will have to install curl from source to get http2 support. You can do that using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential nghttp2 libnghttp2-dev libssl-dev
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.63.0.tar.gz
tar xzf curl-7.63.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.63.0
./configure --with-nghttp2 --prefix=/usr/local --with-ssl
make && sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: @user535733 Can you please explain why ?

Comment: I find that uninstalling the packaged version first is a good idea for two reasons: 1) It prevents system conflicts (Error: /usr/bin/curl already exists). 2) It prevents user confusion (I *thought* I was using the new one)

Comment: @user535733 . Thanks, this will install curl inside /usr/local So it won't collide with the default installation. You can even use them side by side.

Comment: Trying to install libnghttp2-dev gives dependencies issues:
libnghttp2-dev : Depends: libnghttp2-14 (= 1.7.1-1) but 1.10.0-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is to be installed
How to fix?

Comment: okey fixed it, downgraded to the required version:
sudo apt-get install libnghttp2-14=1.7.1-1

Comment: If it's still not working, then you may need to restart shell or clear your hash if you've used `/usr/bin/curl` lately. https://askubuntu.com/q/923527/453746

Comment: Most likely you'll want to compile with ssl support as well. Then install `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` first and add run configure command this way: `./configure --with-nghttp2 --prefix=/usr/local --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl`

Comment: @Stalinko I think it is enabled by default, can you please confirm?

Comment: @Tachyons in my case it wasn't. I think it depends on env settings. When you don't pass this parameter deliberately then `configure` reads it from env variables `OPENSSL_CFLAGS` and `OPENSSL_LIBS`

Comment: I did it exactly, no error message, but `curl -V` doesn't list HTTP2 in Features.

Comment: @TiborNagy Try /usr/local/bin/curl -V

Comment: @Tachyons `curl -V` is using also the correct path, ` /usr/local/bin` is at the beginning of my $PATH and I see also from the version, that the correct curl instance is called. BTW the output is `url 7.63.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-12-12
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets`