# Why does `which` point to a different binary?

Tags: command-line, bash, paths

I have 2 versions of curl installed on my system, one with http2 support.

I thought I could use `which` to point to the binary, but it doesn't seem to work the way I expect.

```
$ curl --http2 -I https://something.example.com
curl: (1) Unsupported protocol
$ which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl
$ /usr/local/bin/curl --http2 -I https://something.example.com
HTTP/2 200  
server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)  
date: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 20:55:09 GMT  
content-length: 928  
last-modified: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 19:43:10 GMT  
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000  
accept-ranges: bytes
```

`which` is pointing to my locally built binary `/usr/local/bin/curl` but the actual command is executing the package binary `/usr/bin/curl`

I don't have an alias for curl, so can someone please explain to me why this is so? And what command should I run to find the actual path to curl, which I happen to know is `/usr/bin/curl`

Comment: What does `type curl` say? it may be hashed by the shell

Comment: it does say `curl is hashed (/usr/bin/curl)` so does that mean it takes precedence over the `PATH`?

Comment: It's essentially the same issue as this: [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/a/861386/178692) - you can use `hash -r curl` to "forget" the hashed location, after which the order in your `PATH` will be respected

Answer (score 2):

If you run:

```
echo $PATH
```

You are going to get something similar to:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

As you can see, `/usr/local/bin` has a higher priority, so bash will find your locally installed version of curl first and stop searching any more.

You can change this behavior by editing `PATH` environment variable, e.g (in `.profile`):

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `which` would find it in the same order that my command would. The answer is that it was hashed, skipping the `PATH`. See the comments.

Comment: I saw it ;) I leave this answer here, it might be helpful to others :-)

Comment: still "which" should follow the same path, what a mess